# Twig Base functions not working after custom extension made

Tags: php, symfony, twig

TL;DR: I made a custom twig Extension and now twigs base functions don't work

So a little backstory. I have this one twig file (masterMacro.html.twig) that holds references to all of my twig macros. I was attempting to create a twig global variable that would allow me to not have to import the masterMacro.html.twig on each page but rather just call the global variable.

To illustrate. Instead of having to do this

```
{% import 'FooBarbundle:Macros:masterMacros.html.twig' as macros %}
{{ macros.fooMacro() }}
```

I was trying to make it so that I would only have to do:

```
{{ FooBarMacros.fooMacro() }}
```

So I wrote this custom extension that looks like this:

```
/** FooBarBundle\Twig\Globals\FooBarBundleMacrosGlobal.php */
<?php

namespace Bar\FooBarBundle\Twig\Globals;


class FooBarBundleMacrosGlobal extends \Twig_Extension{

    /**
         * Returns a list of global variables to add to the existing list.
         *
         * @return array An array of global variables
         */
        public function getGlobals()
        {

            $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('/web/bar/Bar/FooBarBundle/Resources/views/Macros'));

            $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

            return array(
              'FooBarMacros' => $twig->loadTemplate('masterMacro.html.twig')
            );
        }

        public function getName(){
            return 'FooBarMacros';
        }

}
```

And then registered it as a service

```
services:
    foobar.twig.FooBarMacrosGlobal
        class:     Bar\FooBarBundle\Twig\Globals\FooBarMacrosGlobal
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

So the good news is that the global macro worked. I can now call just the FooBarMacros.fooMacro() and everything works. HOWEVER, now none of the normal twig functions work.

For example I'm trying to use dump like so and I get there following error:

```
{{ dump('hello world') }}
The function "dump" does not exist in myTemplate.html.twig at line 219
```

Any clue whats going on? This is my first twig extension, so I'm sure I screwed something up there.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Drew Landgrave

Answer (score 1):

My assumption:

You create a new instance of \Twig_Environment. Maybe this is used in any way after by Symfony and this obviously has no functions defined by any extension.

Looking into the manual, there is a [initRuntime](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Extension.html#method_initRuntime) method where "[...]you can load some file that contains filter functions for instance". As a parameter, you have the global \Twig_Environment instance available.

So, I would try to put the $twig->loadTemplate() into initRuntime(), save the returned object into a object variable and return this in getGlobals()